# ViewPatterns affects typechecking in an unpredictable manner

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the following code snippet:

```
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as V

bar :: Int -> UV.Vector Char -> (Text, Text)
bar i v = (t_pre, t_post)
  where
    f = T.pack . V.toList
    (t_pre, t_post) = (\(x, y) -> (f x, f y)) $ V.splitAt i v
```

This compiles ok as you might expect. However, if you replace the function calls with view patterns, you get a type error.

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as V

bar :: Int -> UV.Vector Char -> (Text, Text)
bar i v = (t_pre, t_post)
  where
    f = T.pack . V.toList
    (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
```

This prints the following message (with `-fprint-potential-instances`):

```
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘v0’ arising from a use of ‘V.toList’
      prevents the constraint ‘(V.Vector v0 Char)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include
    f :: v0 Char -> Text (bound at Weird.hs:11:5)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘v0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
    instance V.Vector UV.Vector Char
      -- Defined in ‘Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base’
    ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
      instance primitive-0.6.3.0:Data.Primitive.Types.Prim a =>
               V.Vector Data.Vector.Primitive.Vector a
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Vector.Primitive’
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘V.toList’
      In the expression: T.pack . V.toList
      In an equation for ‘f’: f = T.pack . V.toList
   |
11 |     f = T.pack . V.toList
   |                  ^^^^^^^^

Weird.hs:13:6: error:
    Variable not in scope: f :: UV.Vector Char -> t
   |
13 |     (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
   |      ^

Weird.hs:13:18: error:
    Variable not in scope: f :: UV.Vector Char -> t1
   |
13 |     (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
   |                  ^
```

My understanding is that both the ways of expressing things are entirely equivalent, because a view pattern is just function application without naming the bound variable. Am I misunderstanding view patterns? Is it the desugaring that is interacting with the type checker in an unexpected manner? If I inline the definition of `f` at both the call sites, the type error goes away.

I've tested this with GHCi 8.4.3.

---

Update: This is a compiler bug. See GHC Trac [#14293](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/14293) for more details.

Comment: As far as I know `ViewPatterns` is kind of syntactic sugar for function pattern matching, Not function application. The sintax is `function -> Constructor`. Try by matching the pattern `( , )`

Comment: You can't pattern match on a function though, you can only apply a function. `f = show`. Then `(f -> x, f -> y) = (1, 2)` in GHCi after `:set -XViewPatterns`. It will give you `x == "1"` and `y == "2"`.

Comment: Based on the answers, it seems like a bug. I've created a [ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/15893#ticket) for confirmation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with `f` which is caused by the monomorphism restriction.  If you eta expand `f`, give it a type signature, or turn on `NoMonomorphismRestriction`, then this error will go away.

But you're still left with these errors, which came as a surprise to me!

```
Weird.hs:13:6: error:
    Variable not in scope: f :: UV.Vector Char -> t
   |
13 |     (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
   |      ^

Weird.hs:13:18: error:
    Variable not in scope: f :: UV.Vector Char -> t1
   |
13 |     (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
   |                  ^
```

I guess view patterns don't work if they are defined in the same scope.  To see if view patterns needed to be top-level, I tried

```
bar :: Int -> UV.Vector Char -> (Text, Text)
bar i v = let (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v in (t_pre, t_post)
  where
    f = T.pack . V.toList
```

which worked fine.  So I tried

```
f = T.pack . V.toList
(f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt 0 UV.empty
```

Which fails with `f` not in scope.

Finally, if I put those patterns under a function call

```
f = T.pack . V.toList
g (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt 0 UV.empty
```

then it's fine again.  So I guess the rule is that a "value" pattern binding can't use a view pattern which is defined in the same scope.  I find that weird, it might even be a bug.

Comment: Note that, weirdly, in some cases we can define `f` in the same scope (see my answer at the bottom). I have no idea on what triggers the error, and I suspect some interaction with type inference, but it's only a guess.

Comment: @chi No, I still get failures for pattern bindings not under a function (there has to be a name for these!).  E.g. `let f = id ; (f -> x) = () in x` fails.

Comment: Argh. So that matters as well. Too weird, it must be some bug. Moreover, `let f = id in let (f -> x) = () in x` works...

Answer (score 3):

This is quite weird indeed. It might be a bug.

Modifying the original code as follows

```
where
f x = T.pack (V.toList x)
(f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
```

makes GHC ask for `FlexibleContexts`. After doing that, we get a very strange error:

```
    Variable not in scope: f :: UV.Vector Char -> t
   |
12 |     (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
   |      ^
    Variable not in scope: f :: UV.Vector Char -> t1
   |
12 |     (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
   |                  ^
```

This seems like a bug to me. `f` should be in scope there.

Moving `f` to global scope:

```
   ...
   where
   (f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v

f x = T.pack (V.toList x)
```

The code now works just fine. It even works if we revert the global `f` to the pointfree definition.

Using an explicit type annotation, as in

```
where
f :: UV.Vector Char -> Text
f x = T.pack (V.toList x)
(f -> t_pre, f -> t_post) = V.splitAt i v
```

produces a puzzling error message

```
• Variable not in scope: f :: UV.Vector Char -> t
• Perhaps you meant ‘f’ (line 12)
```

I can't understand what's really going on. In GHCi, both these work fine

```
> let f = id ; foo (f -> x) = x in foo ()
()
> let bar = foo () where {f = id ; foo (f -> x) = x} in bar
()
```

Hence, we can use a local `f` in view patterns. Still, when the type of `f` needs some more careful type inference (?), then it can not be used in view patterns. This looks like a bug. At the very least, the error message should be more clear.

Comment: Answers in stereo :-P